# Print object's property using map to jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this set of data

```
const data = [{
    date: '2017-1-1',
    abc: 1,
    def: 2
},{
    date: '2017-1-2',
    abc: 3,
    def: 6
}]
```

How can I print

```
on date of 2017-1-1
abc is equal to 1 and def is equal to 2

on date of 2017-1-2
abc is equal to 3 and def is equal to 6
```

I'm stuck on getting the abc and def property out to jsx. If I do data.map(o => o.abc) I can get 1 but how bout getting the property out using map? Or I should use `Object.keys` and forEach??

I can't hardcode abc or def coz it might have other new properties.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
  {
    date: '2017-1-1',
    abc: 1,
    def: 2,
  },
  {
    date: '2017-1-2',
    abc: 3,
    def: 6,
  },
];

data.forEach((o) =>
  console.log(
    `on date of ${o.date} \nabc is equal to ${o.abc} and def is equal to ${o.def}\n`
  )
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const data = [
    {
      date: '2017-1-1',
      abc: 1,
      def: 2,
    },
    {
      date: '2017-1-2',
      abc: 3,
      def: 6,
    },
  ];

  data.map((o) =>
    console.log(
      `on date of ${o.date} \nabc is equal to ${o.abc} and def is equal to ${o.def}\n`
    )
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

using template literal. something like:

```
data.map(o => `on date of ${o.date} abc is equal to ${o.abc} and def is equal to ${o.def}`)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use `forEach` instead of map, as you are not interested in getting new Array**

try below solution

```js
const data = [{
    date: '2017-1-1',
    abc: 1,
    def: 2
},{
    date: '2017-1-2',
    abc: 3,
    def: 6
}];

data.forEach(function(item){
    var output = [];
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    if(key !== "date")
        output.push(key +" is equal to "+item[key]);
});

console.log("on date of "+item.date+" "+ output.join(" and "));
})
```

Comment: @Debabrata, please read again, as i mentioned i dont need array, hence i dont wanna use map

Comment: @CeciliaChan, i have updated solution, for dynamic key value pair

Comment: @Debabrata, are you kidding me, clear your facts, forEach returns undefined and map returns Array

Comment: @CeciliaChan, is it what you expected?